# Arduino compile error "expected primary-expression before ')' token"

Tags: compilation, arduino

When i attempt to compile the code [HERE](http://pastebin.com/1B5iUUh4W)
I get the error "expected primary-expression before ')' token" and it highlights this line:

```
  sensors.setResolution(insideThermometer, TEMPERATURE_PRECISION);
```

Comment: `#define TEMPERATURE_PRECISION` in line 13 is empty, so it will expand to an empty token: `sensors.setResolution(insideThermometer, );`, which is illegal syntax.

Comment: Thanks, you should add that as an answer so i can give you points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that this does not still come up in "unanswered", I'll answer it... As wildplasser said, i forgot to define the `#define TEMPERATURE_PRECISION` line...